# Arithmetic with computed statistics and variables in ggplot2 aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following example where I (unnecessarily) state that the estimated density values computed by `stat_density()` should be mapped to `y`:

```r
ggplot(economics, aes(x = pce)) + 
  stat_density(aes(y = stat(density)))
```

It is fine to use arithmetic in the mapping if this involves a suitable vector, e.g.

```r
ggplot(data = economics, aes(x = pce)) + 
  stat_density(aes(y = stat(density) * 2))
```

but variables (other than `pce`) from `economics` are not found (just for illustration -- I know that this is not very meaningful from a statistics persepctive):

```r
ggplot(data = economics, aes(x = pce)) + 
  stat_density(aes(y = stat(density) * pop))

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'pop' not found
```

Is there a way to do such "on-the-fly computations" using variables from the dataframe passed to `data`?

Comment: No it is not, which is documented in the note in `?after_stat()` (which is the replacement of the `stat()`  function). You can use variables from the computed statistics or global environment. For example `y = after_stat(density * economics$pop)` is syntactically valid, but you'll note from the error that whatever global variable you put in, must match the length of the computed statistic (which is of length 512 for 1-group KDEs), or be of length 1.

Comment: @teunbrand I see. Thank you!